# Add sort variable at end of URL and manipulate if already exists in URL

Tags: php, sorting, url, get, href

Hi I had URLs like this...

```
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars&loc=Ludhiana
```

And to sort results, sort variable was appending at last of URL and URL after adding sort variable was

```
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars&sort='**ANYVALUE**'
www.example.com/list.php?type=vehicles&stype=Cars&loc=Ludhiana&sort='**ANYVALUE**'
```

And on href i was using

```
<a href="?<?php echo http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array('sort' => 'sort-value'))); ?>"></a>
```

Above code was working perfectly for me. It was adding sort variable at end of URL as i want. Also it was modifying the value of sort variable if variable was existing already in URL.

But then i made my URLs SEO friendly and URLs now are

```
www.example.com/vehicles/Cars
www.example.com/vehicles/Cars/Ludhiana
```

After adding sort variable it becomes

```
www.example.com/vehicles/Cars&sort='**ANYVALUE**'
www.example.com/vehicles/Cars/Ludhiana&sort='**ANYVALUE**'
```

But now as URLs are SEO friendly, So when i use same href, it doesn't work and it becomes

```
http://www.example.com/type=vehicle&stype=Car&sort=R-ASC
```

which results in a 404 error.

What will be the right href code so that it could do the following

1. Append sort variable at the end of URL, whether the URL has 2 varibles or 3 variables.
2. If sort variable already exists in URL, it will manipulate its value with current href.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: How are you building your urls now?

Comment: That is what i want...

Comment: i need href code that will get the whole URL as it is and will append sort variable at last....And if sort variable is already there in URL, then it will manipulate the current sort value keeping rest of the URL same...

Answer (score 0):

The first parameters char should be an **?**.

```
http://www.example.com/?type=vehicle&stype=Car&sort=R-ASC
```

Comment: i need href code that will get the whole URL as it is and will append sort variable at last....

Comment: And if sort variable is already there in URL, then it will manipulate the current sort value keeping rest of the URL same...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what do you need, but try something like that:
Random HTML form that gets the attributes and their values (like ?type=vehicle&stype=blabla) and redirects you to the page you want (pure HTML used, without any PHP):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://example.com" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type" name="type">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Stype" name="stype">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Also if you want a link to the page instead of getting redirect

```
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type" name="type">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Stype" name="stype">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<?php
echo "<a href='http://example.com/listItems.php?type=". $_GET["type"] ."&stype=". $_GET["stype"] ."'>Link</a>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope i helped you less or more.